# What will be default scope while we use @inject

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Since when comparing with spring the default scope is singleton. is that the same in javax inject?? If we need to change the scope how can we achieve???

```java
class A{
    @inject
    B b

    public void method1(){
        .....
        b.invoke();
        ...
    }
}

class B{
    public void invoke(){
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `@Scope` annotation

Comment: Thanks, if not used what will be the scope in javax?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Springs default scope is singleton. [But Springs definition of singleton is probably not like yours](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton):

> Only one shared instance of a singleton bean is managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring container.

Singleton scope means using the same bean id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does singleton in spring mean that they don't share same memory location(i.e all the instance referred have different mem location)?